Error when approximating definite integral
I'm trying to approximate an integral with singularity:
$\int_{2.3}^{2.9} \frac{3cos(2.5x)e^{\frac{7x}{4}}+5sin(0.5x)e^{\frac{3x}{8}}+4}{(2.9 - x)^{\frac{2}{5}}}$
I need to use Newton-Cotes formula with weight function for three evenly spaced nodes: $x_{1}=2.3, x_{2}=2.6, x_{3}=2.9$. Integral is then represented as this:
formula
In my case:
$p(x) = \frac{1}{(2.9 - x)^{\frac{2}{5}}}$
This is the code I wrote:
import math
import numpy as np

def F(x):
    return f(x) / p(x)

def p(x):
    return 1 / ((2.9 - x) ** (2 / 5))

def f(x):
    return (3 * math.cos(2.5 * x) * math.exp((7 * x) / 4) + 5 * math.sin(0.5 * x) * math.exp((3 * x) / 8) + 4)        

# antiderivatives
def n0(x):
    return (-1) * x ** (1 - (2 / 5)) / (1 - (2 / 5))

def n1(x):
    return -2.9 * x ** (1 - (2 / 5)) / (1 - (2 / 5)) + x ** (8 / 5) / (8 / 5)

def n2(x):
    return -2.9 * x ** (1 - (2 / 5)) / (1 - (2 / 5)) + 2 * 2.9 * x ** (8 / 5) / (8 / 5) - x ** (13 / 5) / (13 / 5)

def N0(a, b):
    return n0(2.9 - b) - n0(2.9 - a)

def N1(a, b):
    return n1(2.9 - b) - n1(2.9 - a)

def N2(a, b):
    return n2(2.9 - b) - n2(2.9 - a)

def newton_cotes(m, h):
    res = 0
    for j in range(m):
        a = left + j * h
        b = a + h
        middle = (a + b) / 2
        nodes = [a, middle, b]
        ms = [N0(a, b), N1(a, b), N2(a, b)]
        M = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
                      [nodes[0], nodes[1], nodes[2]],
                      [nodes[0] ** 2, nodes[1] ** 2, nodes[2] ** 2]
                      ])
        A = np.linalg.solve(M, ms)        
        print(ms)        
        for i in range(n):
            res += A[i] * f(nodes[i])
    return res

left = 2.3
right = 2.9
alpha = 0
beta = 2/5
n = 3
eps = 10e-6
true_val = 348.8181344258675

m = 1
h = (right - left) / m

print(newton_cotes(m, h))

Result is 5501.831780809356 which is too big for 348.8181344258675. I can't find my mistake. Could somebody please help me understand what is wrong here? Thanks in advance.

As a general remark, try to use the numpy versions of the sine, cosine, and exponential functions. These are faster than the math versions, and work for both scalars and vectors.

@SnorkMaiden: Don't you have a division by zero for the upper limit?

@Moo Yes, but I think I am still able to approximate the value. I have this function p(x) that takes handle of this division. I need to calculate extra integrals of 1/p(x), x/p(x) and x^2/p(x) and then solve system of linear equations.

You might just be getting weird numerical behavior because of the vertical asymptote at the right endpoint.

FWIW, WolframAlpha approximates the integral as $348.818$.

@Dan yes, I have this as true_value

@Dan is there a way to approximate the integral even if there is a vertical asymptote?

Use scipy.integrate:

integrate.quad(lambda x: p(x)*f(x), left, right)

Result is $348.81813442516864$
